# C++ скорость копирования файла

Tags: c++

Имеется такой код

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include "sys/statfs.h"

void test();


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    //void test();
    void test();
    return a.exec();
}

void test(){
    FILE *p;
    char result[255];
    int i=0;
    p = popen("rsync --info=progress2 /media/ubuntu/6A7C-E4FE/kernel_src.tbz2 /media/ubuntu/6A7C-E4FE/kernel_src4.tbz2", "r"); //copy the same file to the same drive

    if(!p) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening pipe.\n");
        std::cout << ("Error opening pipe.\n") << std::endl;
    }



    while(!fgets(result,255, p) != NULL ) {
        std::cout << (result) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Он копирует файл с пункта А в пункт А и проверяет скорость файла. По идеи должен мне возвращать строку вывода после того, как команда выполнена. К сожалению, ничего не происходит. Где моя ошибка?

Comment: QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

Comment: return a.exec();

Comment: и используй потоки

Comment: @Akuma925 можно больше информации?

Comment: У Вас нет вызова функции `test`, а есть её повторное объявление. Замените `void test();` на `test();` внутри `main`. А объект `QCoreApplication` вообще не нужен здесь. Вы создали не тот тип проекта просто.

Comment: @Insider, Про потоки если вы реализуетет прсотое копирование то проще делать так  std::ifstream ifs(src_pathName, fstream::binary);
std::ofstream ofs(dpn, fstream::trunc|fstream::binary);ofs<<ifs.rdbuf();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы на предупреждения компилятора не смотрите?

```
/tmp/1 $ g++ -std=c++14 test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function ‘void test()’:
test.cpp:19:36: warning: NULL used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
     while(!fgets(result,255, p) != NULL ) {
```

Зачем вы сначала инвертируете возвращаемое значение `fgets()`, в результате чего получаете `bool` (причём `false` для успешных попыток прочитать), а после проверяете его на не `NULL`?

В вашем случае код будет таким:

```
while (fgets(result, 255, p)) {
    std::cout << (result) << std::endl;
}
```

Т.е. просто уберите всё лишнее.

Comment: К сожалению у меня в qt creator, ничего не показывало такого

Comment: и к сожалению, все еще пока не работает код.

Comment: Ну а саму команду вы выполняли вручную? Потому как у меня ваш вариант ничего не выводит, а этот вполне работает. Ну и верно замечено, что вызова `test()` в `main()` нет, а есть повторное объявление. А уровень сообщений об ошибках повысьте.